# Unit Testing TypeScript with phpstorm or webstorm

Tags: unit-testing, typescript, phpstorm, webstorm

I want to unit test TypeScript with phpstorm or webstorm. How can i set up testing framework in phpstorm/webstorm? Also, how can i use tsUnit Framework in phpstorm/webstorm?

Answer (score 0):

**tsUnit framework** is not supported by WebStorm. But you can run unit tests written in typescript using **karma** (for client-side applications) or **mocha** (server-side). Both test runners are supported by WebStorm/PHPStorm. For Karma, see https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/WI/Running+JavaScript+tests+with+Karma; Mocha: http://blog.jetbrains.com/webstorm/2013/11/webstorm-7-0-2-is-available/, https://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/help/running-mocha-unit-tests.html